# What is the difference between thrust::host_vector and std::vector?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Both allocate memory on the host and I can copy contents to `device_vector` and back using iterators. Why was `host_vector` necessary to include in the API? Does it have something to do with pinned memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't implement pinned memory.

I suspect it exists to implement a few overrides, such as assignment from a `device_vector`.

Also, unlike, the `std::vector` implementation in MSVC, Thrust's `host_vector` doesn't check iterator validity which leads to much faster performance on debug builds (by default).

Comment: It also has the nice property of not being able to be constructed from an initializer list.